# Restricting User on ability to chose maximum items from selectInput

Tags: shiny

Shiny function selectInput() gives an option to select multiple items from the dropdown list with 'multiple = TRUE'

However I want to restrict user on how many items max can be chosen from underlying dropdown list.

Can you please suggest if that is possible with Shiny.

Appreciate for any pointer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this if you define it as `selectizeInput()` instead of `selectInput()`, and use the `options = list(maxItems = n)` parameter.

For example

```
selectizeInput("select", "Select", LETTERS, options = list(maxItems = 4))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to try. However selectizeInput automatically selects the 1st element (here 'A'). How can I stop this from happening? Means, initially I want the input field would remain blank, then user will select Max 4 elements from the list

Comment: Alright, I got the way from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175997/no-default-select

Comment: i think simply adding `selected = NULL` will do the trick, I think the documentation for selectInput mentions that