# R Shiny selectizeInput: set minimum for amount of inputs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, selectize.js

I have a `selectizeInput` with `multiple = TRUE` in a shiny application and I would like to prevent the user from selecting `NULL` (i.e., from leaving it blank). My goal is to ensure that *at least one* item is selected (no matter which one).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146939/restricting-user-on-ability-to-chose-maximum-items-from-selectinput) question on the opposite problem (i.e., limiting *maximum* number of selections) and I checked [selectize documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md). Unfortunately, there seem to be no `minItems` option. Is there a way to achieve my desired functionality?

Minimum example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "testSelect",
      label = "Test",
      choices = LETTERS[1:4],
      selected = LETTERS[1],
      multiple = TRUE,
      # Problem: how to specify 'minItems' here
      options = list(maxItems = 2)
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("selected")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$selected <- renderPrint({
      input$testSelect
    })
  }

)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be an open issue: #https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1228.

Concerning your R/Shiny implementation you could use a workaround with `renderUI()`.

You would build the input on the server side and control the selected choices.
Before you build the input on the server side you can check the current value and if it does not fulfill your requirement you can overwrite it:

```
selected <- input$testSelect
if(is.null(selected)) selected <- choices[1]
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
choices <- LETTERS[1:4]  
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("select"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selected")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$selected <- renderPrint({
      input$testSelect
    })

    output$select <- renderUI({
      selected <- input$testSelect
      if(is.null(selected)) selected <- choices[1]
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "testSelect",
        label = "Test",
        choices = choices,
        selected = selected,
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(maxItems = 2)
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: thank you for accepting. Feel free to upvote. Or ist there still something that can be added?

Comment: Thanks, this helped to solve my problem. The only thing that can be added: I think it is more natural to replace null by the last non-null value (i.e., if you attempt to remove "B", the code will get "B" back rather than always "A" (choices[1])). I achieved than with adding to sever: `nonNull <- reactiveVal("A"); observeEvent(input$testSelect, {nonNull(input$testSelect)})` and changing 'replacing' code to: `if(is.null(selected)) selected <- nonNull()`