# Multiple Separate Plots on User select/multi input

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, selectinput

I want to visualize plot/s based on user input. I have a dropdown menu and if the user select one or more variables out of the choices given, the code automatically visualize the separate plots for each variable based on the user inputs.

Code: This is how I tried to do it. If there is any other way, please suggest.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), #Necessary to activate shinyjs
    selectInput("select", "Select plot:", 1:4, multiple = TRUE),
    plotOutput("p1"),
    plotOutput("p2"),
    plotOutput("p3"),
    plotOutput("p4")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$p1 <- renderPlot({ plot(iris) })
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({ plot(mtcars) })
    output$p3 <- renderPlot({ plot(0) })
    output$p4 <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })
    
    observeEvent(input$select, {
      req(input$select)
      shinyjs::toggle("p1", condition = input$select == 1)
      shinyjs::toggle("p2", condition = input$select == 2)
      shinyjs::toggle("p3", condition = input$select == 3)
      shinyjs::toggle("p4", condition = input$select == 4)
    })
    
  }
)
```

The problem with this code is that when I select any one input from the dropdown menu, all the other plots for other variables show up too.
Plus when all the variables are selected and I try to unselect variable/s from the dropdown menu, they does not hide.

Comment: Perhap also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234636/13513328

Comment: @Waldi , could you help with another thing? The generated plot based on user selection overlaps the first plot as user input increases. Plus plot width has some problem which basically hides a little bit of portion under the sidebar on the left side. I'm attaching screenshot for this problem. [link] (https://imgur.com/BUJbJhU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the selection allows multiple choice, you should use `%in%` instead of `==`.
You should also use `observe` instead of `observeEvent` to react on `NULL` input.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), #Necessary to activate shinyjs
    selectizeInput("select", "Select plot:", 1:4, multiple = TRUE),
    plotOutput("p1"),
    plotOutput("p2"),
    plotOutput("p3"),
    plotOutput("p4")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$p1 <- renderPlot({ plot(iris) })
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({ plot(mtcars) })
    output$p3 <- renderPlot({ plot(0) })
    output$p4 <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })

    observe({
      shinyjs::toggle("p1", condition = isTRUE(1 %in% input$select))
      shinyjs::toggle("p2", condition = isTRUE(2 %in% input$select))
      shinyjs::toggle("p3", condition = isTRUE(3 %in% input$select))
      shinyjs::toggle("p4", condition = isTRUE(4 %in% input$select))
    })
    
  }
)
```